# SQL update map based on coords

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible; I've got a game which has a "rampant AI" which goes around infecting planets on the gameboard. Right now it's infecting pretty much the entire universe without so much as the smallest hint of a coherent strategy... I would ideally like to have it infect an entire "system"--which is designated by coordinates (X0Y0, X-1Y0, etc)..

What I am wondering is--would it be possible via SQL alone to make the "ai" infect planets within the system, before moving on to the next? EG; after all 23 planets in X0Y0 are infected, have it move over to the 4 surrounding systems (X0Y1, X1Y0, X-1Y0, X0Y-1). or would this be better done in PHP alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a procedure that will, when invoked, "infect" the next appropriate planet (or planets) based on the current state of the infection. Clearly that is possible via SQL. The how of doing it would require knowledge of your schema as well as the "rules" for spreading.

The second question is if it would be better done in PHP and that's a matter of opinion. My initial one is that sort of logic is better off your PHP code.

Comment: That's what I was figuring. alright. I was just checking my bases as I'm by no means an expert in SQL and still on a daily basis learn of new fuctions that i've never heard of before.

Comment: If an answer is "useful" then up vote it. If it sufficiently answers the question and is eventually the best/only answer then accept it.

Comment: Thought I did... my bad my internets been sluggish as of late.